# Linked Lists and Constructors

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I came across a large source code that use several types of link list data structures. For example a simple linked lists data structure used in code is uses nextLink node of the Link type and a constructor initializing the object.

```
public class Link {
    public int data1;
    public double data2;
    public Link nextLink;

    //Link constructor
    public Link(int d1, double d2) {
        data1 = d1;
        data2 = d2;
    }

    }
```

On the other hand, another piece of code uses the following data structure(double link list?) :

```
public class ComplexLinkList {

    public static final int NEXT_BLOCK = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public static final int PREV_BLOCK = -1;

    //The var string holds the variable name 
    private String var;

    private int coverStart = PREV_BLOCK;

    private int coverEnd = NEXT_BLOCK;


   //Constructor ( copy Constructor ?)
    public ComplexLinkList(ComplexLinkList p) {
        this.var = p.var;
        this.coverEnd = p.coverEnd;
        this.coverStart = p.coverStart;

    }


 ----
 ----

}
```

The constructor takes an argument of type ComplexLinkList and initializes the fields.  What is the conceptual difference between the two implementation ? Is the second one exactly a linked list?

Comment: The first one is singly linked lists. The second has no links to another element so it is not a linked list.  It is possible that the second one is used to simulate a doubly linked list using another data structure such as an array, but there is no way to know. I suggest read the LinkedList in the source with the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedList means, there are some nodes connected like below diagram. It can be connected one way or double way. Your first class have the member variable nextLink to have the connection with next node. But the second class doesn't has the way to link with another node.

For doubly linked-list, it has 2 member variables to connect with previous node and next node.

[image: Linked-List flow]

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a specialized linked list (not doubly linked) which holds `data1` and `data2` as satellite data. The second one does not make sense but it is definitely not a linked list. I think you should post all the code in that class for us to be able to tell its function.

Comment: That should be comment :) .

Comment: Thanks Adam! I see similar codes in many classes and am guess it a design pattern used across the project. Any guess as to what it may be?